# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess dbcontext scaffold expected assembly attribute named DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute error

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, .net-core, oracle.manageddataaccess

I'm trying to use dotnet core entity framework dbcontext scaffolding to connect to my oracle database for my dot net core project like this below:

`<!-- language: shell -->
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<hostaddress>:<port>/<sid>" Oracle.ManagedDataAccess --table mytablename  -o Models`

I've been able to achieve this as test on mysql with pomelo and mysql.data but the real datasource i need is in oracle db.

`Unable to find expected assembly attribute named DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute in provider assembly Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. This attribute is required to identify the class which acts as the design-time service provider factory.`

Although i understand that it's saying i require an entity framework designer package which i can't find any option for this and i've tried doing this with Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.EFCore but i kept getting a lisence required to use dbcontext scafolding.

Any help or suggestions will be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The `DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute` problem is discussed [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4180739), it explains that Oracle provider for EF Core is necessary which requires ODP for .NET Core provider assembly.

Comment: According to my understanding from the conversation here [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4180739?start=15&tstart=0) using dotnet scaffolding is not not available now and the ongoing beta is limited to a few users, i just need something even if it an alternate solution that works. I'm currently working with a big database and don't have time to type all models.

Comment: Have you tried the "code-first" approach? whats great about code first is that you only need to write the models for the tables that you need.If the database has 1K tables and you only need 2, you write 2 models and youre done. 

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Tutorial_EFCore_NETCore.html

Comment: I have been able to get scaffolding to work with oracle db, i got a link from oracle to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore beta.

Firstly download package from [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/efcorebeta-5198354.html)
1. Unzip Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.2.18.0-beta2.zip to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.2.18.0-beta2
2. Then add assembly reference to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.2.18.0-beta2/lib/netstandard2.0/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
3. Then install the following nuget packages.

Comment: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
4. Then run ef core scaffolding.

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<host>:<port>/ORCL;Connection Timeout=600;min pool size=0;connection lifetime=18000;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore --table table_name_to_scaffold -o Models -f

Comment: or for all tables in database

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<host>:<port>/ORCL;Connection Timeout=600;min pool size=0;connection lifetime=18000;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -o Models -f

Answer (score 1):

[1]. add nuget packages: 
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.18.6; Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 2.18.0-beta3; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.3; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.3; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.3; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.3; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design 1.1.6

[2]. add an executable project targeting .NET Core 2.x that references this project, and set it as the startup project; then make sure there projects build success;

[3]. PM Code:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<host>:<port>/ORCL;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -Tables "<table1>","<table2>" -ContextDir Context -Context <ContextName>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get scaffolding to work with oracle db, i a [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/efcorebeta-5198354.html) got a from oracle to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore beta.

Firstly download package from link

1. Unzip Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.2.18.0-beta2.zip to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.2.18.0-beta2
2. Then add assembly reference to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.2.18.0-beta2/lib/netstandard2.0/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
3. Then install the following nuget packages.

   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
4. Then run ef core scaffolding.

```sh
    dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<host>:<port>/ORCL;Connection Timeout=600;min pool size=0;connection lifetime=18000;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore --table table_name_to_scaffold -o Models -f
```

or for all tables in database.

```sh
    dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<host>:<port>/ORCL;Connection Timeout=600;min pool size=0;connection lifetime=18000;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -o Models -f
```