# Scaffolding Oracle database using DB First Approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, db-first

"Unable to find provider assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project".

Dont Know why this error is comming while scaffolding.

Scaffold command i used.
Scaffold-DbContext -Provider Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core -Connection "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=18.88.**.**)(PORT=1**1))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=C*****C)));User Id=C******C;Password=C*****8;" -OutputDir Models .

These are the package reference in my project

Comment: Did you install the managed assembly via nuget?

Comment: Yes i installed packages via nuget

Comment: Just use EF Core Power Tools

Comment: Provider should be `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: Have you installed all the packages mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55499025/18789859)?